# Copiar datos de un formulario a otro

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo 3 formularios de 3 empleados diferentes, los formularios son identicos, en veces llevan los mismos datos en los tres, hay alguna manera que con javascript pueda copiar en los otros dos formularios la información del primero para evitar llenar los 3?

Comment: Podrías mostrar código, estos formularios están en el mismo html ?

Comment: Perdón, apenas los estoy haciendo por eso no puse el código, pero me pidieron que se hiciera de esa manera para evitar escribir tanto, si el html esta en el mismo script, pense tal vez con un select (onChange) para elegir que empleado copiar a que empleado.

Comment: por favor lee [ask] pues se espera que el usuario que pregunta coloque lo que ha intentado y que aclare en que ha tenido fallos; pues de lo contrario tu pregunta sería de baja calidad y terminaría recibiendo puntos negativos o siendo cerrada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con Jquery, podrias hacer una función que copie datos de dos formularios con estructuras iguales.

```js
function cloneFormularios( $frm1 , $frm2 ) {
        $(':input[name]', $frm2).val(function() {
          return $(':input[name=' + this.name + ']', $frm1).val();
        });
      }
    //Al hacer click en un btn copiar
      $('#copiar').on('click', function() {
        cloneFormularios(  $('#f1') , $('#f2')  );
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="copiar">copiar</button>
    
    <form id="f1">
     <input name="nombre" type="text">
      <input name="btninfo" type=button value="Info">
      <select name="cbTypo">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    
    <form id="f2">
       <input name="nombre" type="text">
       <input name="btninfo" type=button value="Info">
       <select name="cbTypo">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

ya una vez realice algo similar haciendo esto

```
function layout()
{
var layout2 = document.getElementById('layout');
layout2.innerHTML= 

// Acá iría todo el formulario 
;}
```

Una vez realizado esto llamas a esta función en tu vista de esta forma

```
<div id="layout">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    layout();
  </script>

</div>
```

y con eso debería aparecer el formulario que creaste

Answer (score -1):

Puedes obtener el `value` de los campos del primer formulario y asignarlos al nuevo con alguna acción como un botón. Te pongo un ejemplo:

Aquí tengo 3 inputs de tipo texto y un botón.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 offset-4">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Formulario 1" id="c1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Formulario 2" id="c2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Formulario 3" id="c3">
      <button id="boton" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
        Copiar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En el Javascript obtengo el valor del primer input y lo asigno a los otros dos:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('boton');

btn.onclick = () => {
  let c1 = document.getElementById('c1').value;
  let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
  let c3 = document.getElementById('c3');
  c2.value = c1;
  c3.value = c1;
}
```

[Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando en Codepen.](https://codepen.io/wakowarner/pen/rrwXQv)